# Identify IC with label removed

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, components, display, video

I have an IC which is used for a display that has the IC chip number scratched off. The reason being more than likely that the board would be fairly inexpensive to produce but the combo board and display are going for over 100 USD. I have included a photo of the board in this message.

How could one identify this?

[image: PCB]

Comment: That's probably a microcontroller of some sort.  Provided you could find out which one it is and get your hands on a replacement (not an easy task these days!), how do you propose to copy the almost-certainly-proprietary code on it?

Comment: If it's not a micro, it could be an FPGA, which are even harder to do anything with.  At this point, it would be easier to design your own board from scratch.

Comment: Its probably a LCD driver chip

Comment: Unrelated to the actual question, but wow, those wires are *not* well-soldered.

Comment: @Hearth Awful. IPC will have a meeting about it and strongly condemn it.

Comment: @Hearth You do realize that hobbyists buy these boards and they need to solder in whatever wires they need themselves? It's not a factory solder job.

Comment: @Justme They said they bought a board and display, I assumed they were already connected from the factory.

Comment: ROFL Unknown device in an unknown device.  You could at least throw us a bone and say what one of the unknows are!

Comment: @New did you solder the wires to the board? ... if you did, then why are the wires not inserted into the holes?

Answer (score 4):

It definitely is not a MCU or FPGA.

The system MCU is on bottom left and it's a NXP LPC11xx.

The chip in question is a video decoder chip as it can receive composite, S-Video, RGB and composite separate sync, digitizing and decoding PAL/NTSC and outputs digital video on a parallel bus to a TFT module.

It could be a generic video decoder IC with parallel output, or depending on what kind of displays it connects to, it might be a specific chip intended to be connected to various TFT modules at various or programmable screen resolutions.

Could be some common generic standard chip available from open market, or some very cheap Asian closed market market chip specific to portable TVs/DVD players etc, so even if chip type is known, no data sheet will be available unless you buy them in large quantities.

As there is only 9 wires going from chip to display, grouped as 8+1, it likely uses standard 8-bit BT.656 interface. This is confirmed by the product link and the TFT module data sheet, which says it accepts standard digital YCbCr 4:2:2 video with 720x480 resolution over 8-bit multiplexed Y/C bus.

Answer (score 2):

No easy way, but if you compare with other ICs with similar function and eliminate ones that don't match the package and pinout (for power, clock, reset and anything else you can identify) then you may be able to narrow it down.

The presence of a 24MHz crystal with load capacitors is a hint. Also if several traces from connector CN6 go to the chip, then that's probably an MCU with a programming interface and you'll not be able to copy the board and have it work, even with the right part number, since the manufacturer will have loaded their proprietary code and set the security lock.

Of course there are potentially illegal and most likely unethical ways of getting code from even a locked MCU so taking the numbers off may be a precaution to slow down such folks a bit.

Comment: this drives the following display: https://www.amazon.com/Hilitand-3-5inch-Display-Module-LQ035NC111/dp/B07HR4MSNM would that help in identifying it?

Comment: It’s probably an MCU with a hardware LCD controller peripheral.

Comment: Nope, it is not MCU, the MCU is the other chip.

Comment: @Justme yes that appears to be an NXP MCU. The big chip could be an LCD driver chip of some kind then.